# How do I insert fields in a sharepoint list via access? (with choice fields)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, custom-list, microsoft-access

I'm trying to import a year's worth of data from an 2010 sharepoint server list to a new 2016 sharepoint server list:

- I've built the 2016 list to mirror the 2010 list design, and linked to both from MS access.
- I've built an access query that shows the last 365 day's of data from the 2010 sharepoint list.

Ideally, I'd like to take these results and INSERT INTO the 2016 sharepoint list, but I've got to address the following conundra:

- Both the 2010 and 2016 list have columns of type "Choice (menu to choose from)"
- Both the 2010 and 2016 list have columns of type "Calculated (Calculation based on other columns)"
- Both the 2010 and 2016 list have a date column where the date is [Today's date].

For each of the above situations, I'd like to transfer the original value of the column.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a couple of similar "migrations" by:

- connecting to SP2010 list from MS Access,
- converting the list to
  local table (the menu item shown after right click on the list name in `All Access Objects` pane),
- deleting unnecessary rows from the local table (in your case that would be everything except the last 365 days - the rows are only deleted from the local table, and not the SP2010 list),
- exporting the local table to the new environment (right click on table name, `Export->Sharepoint list` and set the url of your SP2016 site)

After this procedure, the new list would be created in the new environment, with all the columns from the old list/table and also all the data.

- The choice columns should all be recreated in the new list, with all possible choice values
- The calculated fields formulas would be transfered, so the values would be the same as in the old list.
- The DateTime fields would be transfered, but you should check the default value and fix it manually if it is not set to `Today's date`(*in my test it was not set accordingly, but the values were all transfered to new list*).

Since you have already created the new list in SP2016 site, you could either
try the above procedure (your SP2016 list would not have been overriden - Access would add 1 to the name if the same list name is used) or try the approach with INSERT queries as you mentioned in the question or even open both lists in Access and manualy select rows from the source list and paste them to the destination list.

Comment: This is awesome - I'm going to give this a shot real quick - I think you've got it:  my problem was that if I was referencing the list live, as opposed to a local table.

Comment: Damjan, this is a huge help!  Thanks so much.  Question:  You mentioned that the calculated fields' formulas would transfer, but instead, I have date and time fields, and can't convert that column to a formula field from sharepoint designer.  Can you add a little more detail on that?  Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, I did some tests with calculated fields which are "Single line of text" and "Number" and didn't have any problems there. Try changing that field from browser (in List settings) instead of SP Designer.